# Leaflet routing machine usage limits

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.draw, leaflet-routing-machine

I want to find out if there are any usage limits for the leaflet routing machine library. In particular what's the maximum number of waypoints that can be supplied as part of routing requests and are there any limits to how many requests can be made e.g. over a 24 hour period?

Answer (score 1):

**Leaflet Routing Machine have builtin [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) routing engine.** and OSRM demo server usage is restricted to reasonable, non-commercial use-cases. 
There is up-time, latency, or data updates guarantee.

The demo server will have a service-wide rate limit of **5000 req/minute.**

For detailed information please check [this URL](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Demo-server)

Comment: How do you get unblocked if you hit this limit?